# switch recycler view layout while loading

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, reload, progress

I would like to switch the recycler view layout while loading so there will be displayed something indicating the progress:

[image]

Comment: So what did you try to do so far?

Comment: Well, I have thought about using the ViewSwitcher: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html But I would like to now the way it is recommended to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing I know of that's built into RecyclerView to handle this. You'll have to implement your own loading behavior

In the same view that owns your RecyclerView you should add a [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html), when you make your call to fetch the data for your RecyclerView hide the RecyclerView and show the ProgressBar. Switch them back once your data is loaded

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!-- Your RecyclerView here -->

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+/progress_bar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```